# Want to add a button to few cells in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 9 rows in my tableview and want to add buttons to only row 1 and 2. When first time the code runs, it shows button on 1 and 2. But when I scroll the tableview, it starts randomly showing for row 4,5,8,9. The code is below. Please advice what I am doing wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d",[indexPath row]];            
    if([indexPath row] == 0 || [indexPath row] == 1)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake. When you want something in only some cells, you need to reset the value in the other cells.

```
if([indexPath row] == 0 || [indexPath row] == 1) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Basically, for any given cell identifier, you need to set the same set of properties for every index path. If you only set a property for some index paths, then as the cells get reused you will start seeing issues.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting the answer (after the required timeout) is good enough.